# PyCharm Импорт из другого проекта Python

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть два проекта (две папки)

```
project1
- directoryM
-- fileA

project2
- directoryN
-- fileB
```

Как в fileA осуществить импорт класса из fileB

Делаю так: `from project2.directoryN.fileB import Class` - класс не видит 
Среда разработки PyCharm

ОС Windows, вот скрин проектов joxi.ru/DrlzpRPcJjBW2P

Answer (score 2):

Представим (потому что в вопросе подробная информация отсутствует), что ваша ОС - какой-нибудь Linux, директории проектов находятся в `/home/<user>/PycharmProjects`, а вы импортируете класс под названием `Class` из файла `fileB.py`. Тогда можно сделать так:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/<user>/PycharmProjects/project2/directoryN')
from fileB import Class
...
```

**UPD**. Судя по вашему скриншоту (добавьте его в вопрос, чтобы его могли видеть все и сразу), можно сделать так:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\сборки\inside\3.7.3.150\pages_inside\personnel')
from signatures import DigitalSignatures
...
```

**UPD2**. Хоть это и не так правильно, относительно импортировать свои модули, вы можете сделать довольно кривой *хак*:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..' , '..', '..', '..', 'inside', '3.7.3.150', 'pages_inside', 'personnel'))
from signatures import DigitalSignatures
...
```

Таким образом, мы идем вверх по файловой системе на четыре директории назад (`C:\сборки`), далее попадаем в `C:\сборки\inside\3.7.3.150\pages_inside\personnel`. Вообще, сложно разобраться по скриншоту, *сколько* у вас вложенных директорий, возможно, я запутался из-за неправильного подхода к разработке в вашем случае.

Comment: ОС Windows, вот скрин проектов 
http://joxi.ru/DrlzpRPcJjBW2P 

from pages_inside.personnel.signatures import DigitalSignatures

Comment: Так не подойдет, проект используется не только мной и путь до файла pages_inside  у всех разный.
Ну и способ описанный выше не хочет работать
http://joxi.ru/zANekGZIV0kP29

Comment: @ЕвгенийМичурин тогда у вас неправильно реализован подход к организации разработки, а именно импорта своих модулей. Относительный импорт - это [плохо](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7506006/5980797).

Comment: @ЕвгенийМичурин добавил хак, но возможно запутался в куче ваших директорий, но общий смысл вы поняли, я думаю.

Comment: Сделайте второй проект пакетом, добавьте в него файл __init__.py. Хотя, честно, не понятна ваша структура проекта.

Answer (score 0):

B PyCharm нужно зайти в `Settings/Project Structure` и нажать `Add Content Root` справа.

Указать пупку с другим проектом, исключить папки `venv` и `.idea`.

Тогда будут работать стандартные `from AnotherProject import NeddedModule`.